# Dependent exposed filters and taxonomy level Drupal 7

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, input-formats

I have an exposed filter in a View. There you must select **Brand** of car. The taxonomy vocabulary is **Cars**, and has all brands as parents and all **models** of car at the second level under its mother term. When I try to make a expose filter linked to the first level of taxonomy, I don't know how to do it, and less to use the selected result to filter the second exposed filter, which will just render the second level taxonomy term (model).

Comment: I am also looking for the answer about this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Finally, I had to hard-code it and use hook functions. As you see, no answers for a year. I can publish the hard-code solution if you want.

Comment: Yes. That would be great, Please post your answer.

Comment: To avoid repeating myself, here you can find the code of the proposed solution. The code works perfectly in most browsers. I cannot find the original source if it is not in the post itself, I modified it to make it work for my example. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182831/change-the-disabled-status-of-a-form-element-via-ajax/182837

Comment: I don't see how that is related. The link you posted is related to AJAX,where this question is about exposed filters in view.Can you tell me which hook you used for views exposed filters?

Comment: You are right. Maybe I changed to customary filters instead of exposed filters because of this limitation. Finally I had to hard-code it. This behaviour is extremely common and should be included in the Views module itself. It is really frustrating, sometimes I feel that some of the websites I should have done them in pure PHP + MySQL + jQuery.